# Cannot figure out how to get Socket to receive data C#

Tags: c#, python, linux, sockets

So what I am specifically trying to do is get a serial proxy going to pipe an arduino into Unity3d to run on linux. System.IO.Ports just doesn't work on linux with unity.

So I have gotten a python based serial proxy script, I have that up and running just fine. I can netcat into that localhost and actually get output from the arduino.

```
nc localhost 8082
g'day from bitty 1.0 -- type 'logout' to disconnect
Connecting to /dev/tty.usbmodem5d11... connected.
HELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLO
```

I have the arduino only printing out HELLO on repeat.

But the serial proxy is up and running, and has data going over it.

Now I am trying to write the code in Unity to receive this data, and I just can't get it to work.

This is my code for that:

```
public Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
public byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

int pinRead = 0;

void Start () 
{
    socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),8082);

}

void Update () 
{
    if (socket.IsBound)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesRead;
            bytesRead = socket.Receive(buffer);
            string incommingdata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            Debug.Log(bytesRead+"   ||   "+incommingdata);

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {


        }
    }
```

bytesRead is ALWAYS 0 and incomingData just doesn't have anything. It connects, and isBound returns true. I just can't get the code right to receive the data and put it in a format that is usable.

Please help. I need to get this working and its far out of my area of expertise. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

So I got this to work using tcpclient objects and some snippets of code that were posted on a random unity blog....

Here it is if anyone wants to see. I would still be really curious to know how to get the Socket implementation functioning though.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

public class ArduinoTest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private bool socketReady = false;
    private TcpClient mySocket;
    private NetworkStream theStream;
    private StreamWriter theWriter;
    private StreamReader theReader;
    private string Host = "localhost";
    private Int32 Port = 9900; 
    private int pinRead = 0;


    void Start () 
    {
        setupSocket();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        string read = readSocket();
        if (read != "")
        {
            int value = int.Parse(read);
            if ( value > 53)
            {
                Debug.Log((value-54)+"  DOWN");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(value+"  UP");
            }
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        writeSocket("logout");
        closeSocket();
    }

    public void setupSocket() 
    {
        try 
        {
            mySocket = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
            theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
            theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
            theReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
            socketReady = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket error:" + e);
        }
    }

    public void writeSocket(string theLine) 
    {
        if (!socketReady)
            return;
        String tmpString = theLine + "\r\n";
        theWriter.Write(tmpString);
        theWriter.Flush();
    }

    public string readSocket() 
    {
        if (!socketReady)
            return "";
        if (theStream.DataAvailable)
            return theReader.Read().ToString();
        return "";
    }

    public void closeSocket() 
    {
        if (!socketReady)
            return;
        theWriter.Close();
        theReader.Close();
        mySocket.Close();
        socketReady = false;
    }

    public void maintainConnection()
    {
        if(!theStream.CanRead) 
        {
            setupSocket();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry I can't post comments yet or would do so there)

BytesRead = 0 typically means the remote side disconnected.

For what it's worth, your code works fine when I run a test TCP server listening for connections on port 8082 and sending out some text messages. So I doubt the problem is on the C# client-side.

Beyond this simple example, "getting this to work" is not necessarily a simple question. Here are a couple things you should keep in mind:

- You are making a blocking Receive call, which means you will need to call Update in a loop.
- TCP is a streaming protocol, so you might get partial messages or many messages bundled together in the same Read call. Look up "TCP Framing" to get more details on this.

Comment: In Unity the Update function is the main game loop, it is getting called at 60 fps.

Also the server did not disconnected, as I have it running in there terminal and it says that my C# code is connected.

Comment: I would guess the problem with your original code is that it tries to make the blocking Receive call more than once at the same time from different threads. Does Unity call Update asynchronously or is it single-threaded? (Sorry I had to comment here instead of in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using telnet on this socket, just to see if you can connect to it.

> telnet 127.0.0.1 8082

Comment: Yes that does show information coming from the localhost server. The same thing that netcat shows.